# Multiple if functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have problem I'm hoping someone could help me with.

I have five different text values in 5 cells. I am trying to combine these values into one cell with a comma in between each. However the trick is that if there is **no** value in (H6) then it must place the word "and" between the cell (F6) and (G6). If there is a value in (H6) then place the word "and" between (G6) and (H6). 
In the same statement I must also include If there is not value in (G6) then it must place the word "and" between the cell E6 and F6.

Please see image attached. I am trying to get the highlighted statements into one cell. So multiple IF statements into one cell. Anyone?

[image]

> =IF(G8=0,(D8)&", "&(E8)&" and "&(F8),(D8)&", "&(E8)&", "&(F8)&" and "&(G8)=IF(H8=0,(D8)&", "&(E8)&", "&(F8)&" and "&(G8),(D8)&", "&(E8)&",
>   "&(F8)&", "&(G8)&" and "&(H8)))

I cant figure out the code.

Many thanks.
Alex

Edit: The original image can be found [here](http://www.yogibox.se/test_sheet.png) if size of the inlined is too small.

Comment: Not really a programming question, probably should move this to SuperUser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't this formula working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748134/why-isnt-this-formula-working)

Comment: @AthomSfere - It seems like a perfectly fine functional programming problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this:

[image]

---

You can use a combination of formulas to get what you want.  First you can string together the cells you want using `trim()`.  Trim will help account for blank cells.

```
=TRIM(D1 & " " & E1 & " " & F1 & " " & G1 )
```

The result is:

[image]

---

Now wrap that with a `substitute` to get your commas in between the strings:

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D1 & " " & E1 & " " & F1 & " " & G1 ), " ", ", "))
```

Result is:

[image]

---

The last step to the wrap that formula with another substitute to replace the last comma with the word 'and'.  I used the count function to find the total number of commas and then replaced the last position.

**Final Formula**

```
=SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D1 & " " & E1 & " " & F1 & " " & G1 ), " ", ", ")),","," and",(COUNTA(D1:G1)-1))
```

Result is this:

[image]

Comment: Genius solution!